# How to get a non-pk value to be the value by which a post request is made in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

As the question states, I'd like to be able to instead of having to pass a PK inside my JSON request in the post request I could pass a different value, like a username "bob" instead of 1.
so the idea is that instead of my request containing:

```
{
    "client": 1,
    "urgent": true,
    "article": 1,
    "quantity": 1,
    "order_to": 1
}
```

it should contain:

```
{
    "client": "bob",
    "urgent": true,
    "article": 234,
    "quantity": 1,
    "order_to": 1
}
```

here are my relevant models:

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = [
    ('NM', 'NORMAL'),
    ('PT', 'PLATA'),
    ('OR', 'ORO'),
    ('PL', 'PLATINO'),
]
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    client_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_TYPE,
        default= 'NM')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ArticleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)

class SupplierModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleModel)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OrderModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey('UserModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gen_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    gen_supplied = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    urgent = models.BooleanField()
    order_to = models.ForeignKey('OrderToModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey('ArticleModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity= models.IntegerField()
```

and Serializer:

```
class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # order_to = OrderToPolymorphicSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        fields = ('client', 'urgent', 'article', 'quantity', 'order_to')
```

Help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be possible using a SlugRelatedField https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

Comment: I'm not getting exactly how to do it. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=UserModel.objects.all()
    )
    article = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='code',
        queryset=ArticleModel.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        fields = ('client', 'urgent', 'article', 'quantity', 'order_to')
```

Comment: The OP wanted to be able to write to the serializer fields, don't think `read_only=True` would work, plus the `slug_field` for client should be `username`

Comment: What I wanna do is to be able to make a request using "username" instead of PK Id, This is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @paula.em.lafon try with the edit I made, think it should work...

Comment: It gives me the following assertion error:

    assert self.queryset is not None or kwargs.get('read_only', None), (
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Comment: @paula.em.lafon have you tried passing the `queryset` parameter to the fields?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: thanks for updating I forgot to delete read only, because I just woke up and haven't eaten

Comment: After deleting read only I get the error I was talking about above. The "AssertionError"

Comment: @paula.em.lafon so I think you would pass `queryset=UserModel.objects.all()` to the `client` field and a similar parameter to the `article` field